# Multiprocessing in Python crashes without explanation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, python-multiprocessing

I have a code for training Neural Networks in Python.

I have two GPUs and a list of different trainings to do.

I want to have the GPUs performing different trainings in parallel.

In each training I perform a 3-fold Validation (I called each fold as "splitset")

I am doing something like I write in the code below and sometime I print some message in order to check whether everything is working fine

```
training_list = [0,1,2]
NUM_OF_PROCESSES = 2
job_queue = Queue()
for training in training_list:
    job_queue.put(training)
start_processes(NUM_OF_PROCESSES,job_queue)



def start_processes(num_of_processes, job_queue):
    device0, device1 = '0', '1'
    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()
    process_dev0 = Process(target=manage_gpus, args=(device0, job_queue,lock),
                           name=device0 + '_Manager')
    process_dev0.start()
    if num_of_processes > 1:
        process_dev1 = Process(target=manage_gpus, args=(device1, job_queue,lock),
                               name=device1 + '_Manager')
        process_dev1.start()
    process_dev0.join()
    if num_of_processes > 1:
        process_dev1.join()



def manage_gpus(device, job_queue, lock):
    while not job_queue.empty():
        trainUid = job_queue.get()
        worker = Process(target=train_and_export_wrapper,
                         args=(trainUid, device,lock),
                         name="Worker_tUid_" + str(trainUid) + "_" + device)
        worker.start()
        worker.join()



def train_and_export_wrapper(trainingUid, device, lock):
    if '0' in device:
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
    elif '1' in device:
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '1'
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(device)
    ...setting parameters...
    print('Device {}: start training {}'.format(device, trainingUid))
    training_function(device,parameters)
    with lock:
        print('Device {}: training {} completed'.format(device, trainingUid))



def training_function(device, parameters):
    splitset_list = [0,1,2]
    for splitsetidx in splitset_list:
        training_set = ...
        validation_set = ...
        test_set = ...
        model = ...
        print('Device {}: start training split {}'.format(device, splitsetidx))
        history = model.fit(...)
        print('Device {}: predictions'.format(device))
        predictions = model.predict(test_set)
        print('Device {}: end of split {}'.format(device, splitsetidx))  
        del training_set, validation_set, test_set, model, history, predictions
```

When I run this code, these are the output I see:

```
Device 0: start training 0
Device 1: start training 1
Device 0: start training split 0
Device 1: start training split 0
Device 0: predictions
Device 1: predictions
Device 0: end of split 0
Device 1: end of split 0
Device 0: start training split 1
Device 1: start training split 1
Device 0: predictions
Device 1: predictions
Device 0: end of split 1
Device 1: end of split 1
Device 0: start training split 2
Device 1: start training split 2
Device 0: predictions
Device 1: predictions
---->HERE DEVICE 0 DOES NOT finish his job on training 0 and immediately starts training 2, while device 1 ends his task correctly.
Device 1: end of split 2
Device 0: start training 2
Device 1: training 1 completed
----> now Device 0 does all the necessary steps regarding training 2, correctly
```

So, what is happening here?
I have two hypotesis: either there is a mistake in my code, either the data I am using is too huge (this is possible) and at a certain point one GPU crashes, it exits from training_function and starts another training.
But, in order to prevent the crash, I am always deleting everything before starting another split/fold, so crashes sohould not happen.

Comment: what have you tried? Adding try/except?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Use try/except to catch exceptions, and also logger to record progress instead of/as well as print statements.

Comment: [tf.distribute.Strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/Strategy) is a TensorFlow API to distribute training across multiple GPUs, multiple machines, or TPUs. Using this API, you can distribute your existing models and training code with minimal code changes. Distributed training with TensorFlow can be found [here](Distributed training with TensorFlow) for more information. Thanks!